# How do I modify a webform submission field right before it is saved?

Tags: 8, webforms

When an end-user is submitting data entered in a Drupal 8 webform, I would like my custom module to modify a field that is on the same form based on values of other fields. I am having trouble accessing the values of the submitted data and also setting the value of the field that I wish to change before being saved.

There is a sample webform API file included which has some starters for hooks. A hook which I found may be useful is the following.

```
function hook_webform_submission_form_alter(array &$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {}
```

I used the `dpm()` to print the values of these variables. The `$form_state` variable has the data submitted, and I know I can use the `$form` variable to change these values before being saved.

How can I get values of the data submitted and also set the value of another field on that same page before the submission is saved? In Drupal 7 this was fairly straightforward, but with Drupal 8 navigating the array and object structures of variables is not as transparent.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `preSave` method in your handler. Please check out the *Webform module handler tests* module which is part of Webform codebase, it has `TestWebformHandler.php` file which defines the submission test handler which displays a status message for every handler event.

For example:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\webform_test_handler\Plugin\WebformHandler;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerBase;
use Drupal\webform\WebformInterface;
use Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface;

/**
 * Webform submission test handler.
 *
 * @WebformHandler(
 *   id = "test",
 *   label = @Translation("Test"),
 *   category = @Translation("Testing"),
 *   description = @Translation("Tests webform submission handler behaviors."),
 *   cardinality = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::CARDINALITY_SINGLE,
 *   results = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::RESULTS_IGNORED,
 *   submission = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::SUBMISSION_REQUIRED,
 * )
 */
class TestWebformHandler extends WebformHandlerBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function preCreate(array $values) {
    $this->displayMessage(__FUNCTION__);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function postCreate(WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
    $this->displayMessage(__FUNCTION__);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function postLoad(WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
    $this->displayMessage(__FUNCTION__);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function preDelete(WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
    $this->displayMessage(__FUNCTION__);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function postDelete(WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
    $this->displayMessage(__FUNCTION__);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function preSave(WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
    $this->displayMessage(__FUNCTION__);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function postSave(WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission, $update = TRUE) {
    $this->displayMessage(__FUNCTION__, $update ? 'update' : 'insert');
  }
}
```

Then you can use a standard ways of modifying your `$webform_submission`.

See also: [Way to do an action after a webform submission has been created](https://www.drupal.org/node/2859218).

Answer (score 4):

After much trial and error, I found an answer with the help of these pages:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2841729

https://www.drupal.org/node/2637958

The idea is to create a custom module and add a validation function using `hook_form_alter()`. The validation function then sets the values before the form is saved permanently with the `setValues()` method.

Here, I am setting the webform element `observations` to an arbitrary value.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form,$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'MYFORM') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#validate'][] = 'MYMODULE_operation_form_validate';
    }
}

function MYMODULE_operation_form_validate(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $values = ['observations' => 777];
  $form_state->setValues($values);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this - I was getting very frustrated trying to find a hook to fire before the webform module purges `$_POST`. One thing I will point out however is that only the first 2 parameters get passed to the `_validate` function, so the inclusion of `$form_id` causes an undefined notice to be triggered.

Answer (score 4):

In Drupal 8 you can use [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/8.4.x), for example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave().
 */
function mymodule_webform_submission_presave(\Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission $submission) {
  // var_dump($submission); exit;
}
```

in order to access, validate or modify the elements of your webform `$submission`.

See: [How to track webform element create, update, and delete operations](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-track-webform-element-create-update-and-delete).

For Drupal 7, see: [How to alter the Webform submission information](https://www.webomelette.com/drupal-webform-submission-presave-hook).

Answer (score 2):

Use this hook `hook_webform_element_alter`

```
/**
 * Implements hook_webform_element_alter().
 *
 * @param array              $element
 * @param FormStateInterface $form_state
 * @param array              $context
 */
function module_webform_element_alter(array &$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, array $context) {
    //use kint
    kint($element);
    //alter location field
    if ($element['#webform_id'] === 'my_form--location') {
        //do the logic
    }
}
```

Bingo!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this.You can use :-

1.hook_webform_element_alter()

```
function your_module_name_webform_element_alter(array &$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, array $context) {
  if (isset($element['#webform_id'])){
    if ($element['#webform_id'] === 'abc') {
        //do the logic
    }
  }
}
```

Follow this for better understanding https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-a-webform-element

2.hook_form_alter()

```
function your_module_name_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'your_form_id') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'your_module_name_form_validate';
  }
}
```

And your logic goes into validate function

```
function your_module_name_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $values = $form_state->getValues();
  //Your logic goes here.
}
```

3. hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()

```
function your_module_name_webform_submission_presave(EntityInterface $entity) {
  // Entity new will only allow you to modify the value for first time. 
  if ($entity->isNew()) {
      $entity->setElementData('key', value);
  }
}
```