# How do I alter webform values before submission?

Tags: 8, webforms

I am trying to add some values to a hidden field in my webform before submission. Is there any hooks to access webform submission in Drupal 8? I tried [How do I modify a webform submission field right before it is saved?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229949/how-do-i-modify-a-webform-submission-field-right-before-it-is-saved) without luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer linked is mostly right, just a couple of updates to get it working. In a custom .module add:

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form,$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'FORMID') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#validate'][] = 'MODULENAME_form_validate';
  }
}

function MODULENAME_form_validate($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setValue('hidden_id', 'Value for Hidden field');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To alter webform values before submission -

In my code, I am changing the timestamp from "Y-m-d HH:MM:SS" to "Y-m-d" format and changing it before saving to DB. Also, i am creating a custom module name as "webform_presave"

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave().
 */

function webform_presave_webform_submission_presave(\Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission $submission) {
  $submissionCreated = $submission->getCreatedTime();
  $submissionCreatedChnaged = format_date($submissionCreated, 'custom_date');
  $a = strptime($submissionCreatedChnaged, '%Y-%m-%d');
  $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $a['tm_mon']+1, $a['tm_mday'], $a['tm_year']+1900);
  $submission->setCreatedTime($timestamp);
}
```